# Как сделать "выпадающую шторку"?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Мне нужно вставить на сайт стрелочку повернутую вниз. Когда на неё нажимаешь, то без обновления страницы, тебе выдвигается какая-то информация.

Как это сделать - CSS, HTML, JS, PHP?

Comment: java то тут причем?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xf9kta8q

Comment: Спасибо, но, сожелению нельзя цвет поменять

Comment: Это называется аккордеон, https://bootstrap-4.ru/docs/4.0/components/collapse/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

оно?)

P.S. dispatch можно удалить

```js
class Accordeon {
  constructor(node) {
    this.node = node;

    if (!this.node) return;

    this.node['_component'] = this;

    this.onAccordeonItemClick = this.onAccordeonItemClick.bind(this);

    this.node.addEventListener('click', this.onAccordeonItemClick, false);
  }

  onAccordeonItemClick(e) {
    const header = e.target.closest('.accordeon__header');

    if (!header) return;

    const parent = header.parentNode;

    if (this.isItemOpen(parent)) {
      this.unsetActiveItem();
    } else {
      this.unsetActiveItem();
      this.setActiveItem(parent);
    }
  }

  isItemOpen(parent) {
    return parent.classList.contains('accordeon__item_open');
  }

  unsetActiveItem() {
    [...this.node.querySelectorAll('.accordeon__item')].forEach(item => {
      item.classList.remove('accordeon__item_open');
      item.querySelector('.accordeon__content').style.maxHeight = null;
    });
  }

  setActiveItem(item) {
    item.classList.add('accordeon__item_open');

    this.slideToggle(item.querySelector('.accordeon__content'));

    this._dispatchAccordeonOpenEvent(item.scrollHeight);
  }

  slideToggle(item) {
    item.style.maxHeight = item.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }

  _dispatchAccordeonOpenEvent(height) {
    const event = new CustomEvent('accordeon:open', {
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true,
      detail: {
        component: this,
        height: height
      }
    });

    this.node.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
}

new Accordeon(document.querySelector('.accordeon'));
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1240px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.accordeon__item {
  margin-bottom: 17px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.accordeon__item_open .accordeon__header-arrow {
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
}

.accordeon__header {
  position: relative;
  padding: 25px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordeon__header-title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.accordeon__header-title-day {
  color: #838383;
  margin-right: 19px;
}

.accordeon__header-title-desc {
  color: #111;
}

.accordeon__header-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 30px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.accordeon__content {
  max-height: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease;
}

.accordeon__content-wrapper {
  padding: 8px 30px 30px 30px;
}

.accordeon__content-wrapper>p {
  margin-bottom: 23px;
}

.accordeon__content-wrapper>p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="accordeon">
    <div class="accordeon__item">
      <div class="accordeon__header">
        <div class="accordeon__header-title">
          <div class="accordeon__header-title-day">1 День.</div>
          <div class="accordeon__header-title-desc">Отправление в Варшаву.</div>
        </div>

        <div class="accordeon__header-arrow">
          <svg width="14" height="9" viewBox="0 0 14 9" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M5.15279 7.70239C5.92365 8.43066 7.12891 8.43066 7.89977 7.70239L12.3968 3.4538C13.712 2.21126 12.8326 0 11.0233 0H2.02925C0.219924 0 -0.659436 2.21126 0.655764 3.4538L5.15279 7.70239Z" fill="#E5E5E5"/>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordeon__content">
        <div class="accordeon__content-wrapper">
          <p>Вы сможете прогуляться по очаровательной пешеходной улице Вильняус, накупить сувениров, литовских национальных напитков и деликатесов.</p>
          <p>Отъезд в Санкт-Петербург.</p>
          <p>Прохождение границы.</p>
          <p>Прибытие в Петербург поздно вечером.p</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordeon__item">
      <div class="accordeon__header">
        <div class="accordeon__header-title">
          <div class="accordeon__header-title-day">2 День.</div>
          <div class="accordeon__header-title-desc">Пешеходная прогулка по Вильнюсу.</div>
        </div>

        <div class="accordeon__header-arrow">
          <svg width="14" height="9" viewBox="0 0 14 9" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M5.15279 7.70239C5.92365 8.43066 7.12891 8.43066 7.89977 7.70239L12.3968 3.4538C13.712 2.21126 12.8326 0 11.0233 0H2.02925C0.219924 0 -0.659436 2.21126 0.655764 3.4538L5.15279 7.70239Z" fill="#E5E5E5"/>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordeon__content">
        <div class="accordeon__content-wrapper">
          <p>2Вы сможете прогуляться по очаровательной пешеходной улице Вильняус, накупить сувениров, литовских национальных напитков и деликатесов.</p>
          <p>Отъезд в Санкт-Петербург.</p>
          <p>Прохождение границы.</p>
          <p>Прибытие в Петербург поздно вечером.p</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordeon__item">
      <div class="accordeon__header">
        <div class="accordeon__header-title">
          <div class="accordeon__header-title-day">3 День.</div>
          <div class="accordeon__header-title-desc">Транзит по территории Чехии, Польши и Литвы.</div>
        </div>

        <div class="accordeon__header-arrow">
          <svg width="14" height="9" viewBox="0 0 14 9" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M5.15279 7.70239C5.92365 8.43066 7.12891 8.43066 7.89977 7.70239L12.3968 3.4538C13.712 2.21126 12.8326 0 11.0233 0H2.02925C0.219924 0 -0.659436 2.21126 0.655764 3.4538L5.15279 7.70239Z" fill="#E5E5E5"/>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="accordeon__content">
        <div class="accordeon__content-wrapper">
          <p>Вы сможете прогуляться по очаровательной пешеходной улице Вильняус, накупить сувениров, литовских национальных напитков и деликатесов.</p>
          <p>Отъезд в Санкт-Петербург.</p>
          <p>Прохождение границы.</p>
          <p>Прибытие в Петербург поздно вечером.p</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```